# Post images & videos to sitecore

Tags: web-services, api, web-content, web-publishing

Is there a way to invoke the sitecore api and post images/videos so that sitecore accepts them and stores it in its own media folder? Or is there a folder where you can place items that get imported into sitecore on set intervals?

Answer (score 2):

The setting  defines the folder that contains media that sitecore wil import into it's media library.
This should help.

Answer (score 1):

Items that you place into the /upload folder will be loaded into the Sitecore Media Library. You can even place a folder structure inside of the /upload folder which will be created in the Media Library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly copy anything in to the ~/upload folder and Sitecore will automatically create the same folder structure in "media library", but there are certain things you need to be aware of, because Sitecore uses System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to upload any files in to "media library" if your copying larger files or some bulk copy/paste you might or might not end up with issues like  some of the files not get uploaded in to "media library", this was an old issue that was related to FileSystemWatcher buffer size, but it might be fixed by now, but I am not sure. And another thing to be aware of, if you delete something back from media library after it was upload automatically, and if the files are still in upload folder, it will not upload them back again until you delete them all and copy/paste again to upload folder.

Hope This helps!